# Query to convert DBRef to Embedded Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edc30b7d1e1f025f78aaac"),
    "_class" : "xyz",
    "name" : "Test Segment 7",
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "attributeName" : "Country",
            "includedAttributes" : [ 
                {
                    "$ref" : "attribute",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("59ddffe8d1f2e34eb9d32f36")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a query to convert includedAttributes to it's equivalent attribute object.

Comment: Properties cannot be prefixed with `$`, because that is reserved for operators and internal use. So that's the "internal" view of a `DBRef` and not something you can "normally" query. What is the purpose for which you believe you need to do this? Is it for reporting purposes? Or do you need to re-write the collection ( actually strongly recommended ). Note this is not possible in a single query. Some drivers "emulate" a "join" by performing additional queries. But there is no possible way for the server to "join" with data in this format.

Comment: Would like to rewrite the colletion, but already having bulk to data in my collection.So need a query to do the update

Comment: Read the comment. The "server" cannot do it. We can "hack it", into "embedded `ObjectId` values" and a plain string denoting the collection namespace. But there is nothing the server can do to "join" the actual data. If you want to embed the "related" data fully, then you need to cycle each document and pull the references manually. Another reason why you don't use `DBRef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me :

```
db.collection1.find({}).forEach(function(row){
        row.attributes.forEach(function(rAttribute){
          if(rAttribute.includedAttributes != undefined){

              var embededAttributeArray = [];
                rAttribute.includedAttributes.forEach(function(iAttr){
                    var embeddedAttribute = db.getCollection('attribute').find({"_id":iAttr.$id}).toArray()[0];
                    embededAttributeArray.push(embeddedAttribute);
                });
                if(embededAttributeArray != undefined){
                    rAttribute.includedAttributes.length = 0; 
                    for(var i=0;i<embededAttributeArray.length;i++) {
                        rAttribute.includedAttributes.push(embededAttributeArray[i])                                 
                    }
                  db.collection1.save(row);
               }
            };
        });
});
```